# Webpack: Trigger a file watch recompile on an unchanged file

Tags: webpack, webpack-5, hot-module-replacement, webpack-dev-middleware, webpack-hot-middleware

I'm developing a Webpack 5 plugin and I need to manually trigger a recompile on a watched file without modifying it (mainly to do some niche HMR stuff).

I figure the easiest way is to convince the compiler that the file has changed. I don't want to actually change the file with *fs*. I've looked into the webpack source code - spoofing webpack's *NodeWatchFileSystem* looks to be very hacky. Triggering a recompile another way is beyond me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tracing backwards all the way to the file watchers, when a file is saved, the file watcher emits the "change" event and the functions that follow consume this event and trigger the recompilation for the changed file.

As we require a "change" event and a recompilation, but for an unchanged file, accessing these consumer functions (`setFileTime(...)`) & simulating the consumption of a "change" event would be a cleaner solution like below, worked great for me!

```
//unchanged file that needs to be recompiled
let filePath = "/Users/my-project/src/HelloWorld.js" 

// Webpack v5.x
compiler.watchFileSystem.watcher.fileWatchers
  .get(filePath)
  .directoryWatcher.setFileTime(
    filePath,
    new Date().getTime(),
    false,
    false,
    "change"
  );

// Webpack v4.x
compiler.watchFileSystem.watcher.fileWatchers
  .find((watcher) => watcher.path === filePath)
  .directoryWatcher.setFileTime(
    filePath,
    new Date().getTime(),
    false,
    "change"
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to recompile watched files (without them actually changing) is to update their timestamps and add them to the modified files on the webpack compiler. Then, invalidating `watching`, making sure to clear the `watcher` first.

This will trigger a new build on just those files, running all loaders, and updating HMR, etc.

```
const time = Date.now();
const timestamps = new Map<string, FileSystemInfoEntry>();
const modifiedFiles = new Set<string>();

// Make an entry for each file path that should recompile
paths.forEach(path => {
  timestamps.set(path, {
    safeTime: time,
    timestamp: time,
    // accuracy: 0,
  });
  modifiedFiles.add(path);
});

compiler.fileTimestamps = timestamps;
compiler.contextTimestamps = timestamps;
compiler.modifiedFiles = modifiedFiles;

// Trigger recompile
compiler.watching.watcher = null; // Otherwise watcher will pull in fresh file data, undoing the compiler modifications above
compiler.watching.invalidate(() => { // Triggers the recompile
  console.log('Recompile finished');
});
```

Comment: This solution worked inconsistently. The above answer is a much cleaner approach.